# Pages nested in wechat miniprogram

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I need in wechat miniprogram to show one page within another.

Using a template is not enough because what I need is that each page executes its own js code.

It is not exactly this, but it would be like putting an iframe from another page that is in my own miniprogram application.

I'm not sure if this is possible. I have searched the net and I have not found anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn to create your own components.

I guess you want to build single application and change a part of page without the other parts in your page. Using components can do this.

You have to know how to create miniprogram-component, communications between component and page or other children-components.

Answer (score 0):

It has been quite a long since this has been posted but is this similar to the question that I have posted recently?
[Open a wechat mini program on top of another mini program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966941/open-a-wechat-mini-program-on-top-of-another-mini-program)

If you have got any answers for the same, please comment it out so that I would be very useful.

It seems that it is possible to embed an iframe on top of the mini-programs but how to perform these are not sufficient with the current weixin public doc.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32937881)